# Why does it work? SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae

```
template<class T, class U>
struct is_convertible
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef struct
    {char _[2];}no;

    static yes test(U);
    static no test(...);
    enum {value = (sizeof(test(0)) == sizeof(yes)) ? 1 : 0};
//THE PART I'M INTERESTED IN IS (test(0)). Why 0 (zero) works here?

};
```

Please see comment in the code.

Comment: Where is that from?  It looks like a bug that it's using `0` rather than something on type `T`.

Comment: That can't be correct.  Template parameter `T` is never used.

Comment: @Downvoters would you at least have guts to explain. What's wrong with this question?

Comment: @ClosingVoters why? Under which point in the list to close this question ends up?

Comment: @There: Probably because the code (almost certainly) doesn't work, and so there isn't really anything to explain.

Comment: Does the code contain `...`, or is that a placeholder for something complicated?

Comment: @Jeremiah So why did I post it under title 'Why does it work' if it wouldn't work, don't you think? Did you at least tried to compile it?

Comment: @There: It's got two votes as "not a real question", because "Why does it work?" is not a real question.  "work" is not defined.  A better question would be "Why does it generate *this output* when invoked with *these inputs*?"  And of course, generate a complete snippet of code.  Almost ANY template code will compile if it's not used, so compiling without errors is a miserable definition of "work".

Comment: @Ben yes, this code contains ellipsis

Comment: @Ben I've tried it in main and it works that's why this whole question. Before commenting on something you should first try it.

Comment: @There: "Compiles" is at least an objective test.  "Gives correct results" is meaningless until you tell us what the expected results are.

Comment: @Ben isn't the name of this metafunction selfexplanatory? Seriously...

Comment: @There: No.  [Here's a user who wanted to test for convertibility in protected context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620968/checking-the-type-of-a-protected-member-function).  That same name could also mean a test for **explicit** convertibility.  It's badly underdefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code "works" when it meets its specification.

This code does not meet the specification implied by the function name, and no clearer specification has been given.

Currently, the code yields `is_convertible<T, U>::value` true when `U` is copyable and an implicit conversion exists in the context of `struct is_convertible` from `int` or any pointer to `U`, may not compile if `U` is not copy-constructible, and false otherwise.

The assumed specification, based on a combination of the name and existing code, is that `is_convertible<T, U>::value` should be true if `U` is copy-constructible (in the context of `struct is_convertible`) and a value of type `T` is implicitly convertible (in the context of `struct is_convertible`) to `U`.

A slight modification is required to make the code meet the implied specification:

```
enum {value = (sizeof(test(*(T*)0)) == sizeof(yes)) ? 1 : 0};
```